# How to utilize $u=x^2+y^2$ and $v=y+z$ to solve $z\frac{\partial{z}}{\partial{x}}+x\frac{\partial{z}}{\partial{y}}+x = 0$

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I am new to partial differential equations and I am quite stuck on this one.

$$z\frac{\partial{z}}{\partial{x}}+x\frac{\partial{z}}{\partial{y}}+x = 0$$

with, $u=x^2+y^2$ and $v=y+z$

I understand this is an introductory level pde. I have tried substituting $y = v - z$ but have not been able to successfully utilize the two relations given by the problem.

Do you have any suggestion on how I should go about this one?

**Edit:**
The independent variables are $x$ and $y$ and the dependent one is $z$. I believe we are meant to find $z(x,y)$ and/or $z(u,v)$.

Comment: May I ask what you are solving? It is not quite clear to me.

Comment: @VezenBU of course, I apologize for the confusion. The dependent variable is z and the independent ones are x and y. We are looking for z(x,y) (or possibly z(u,v) not quite so sure). I will add this to the question

Answer (score 3):

$$z\frac{\partial{z}}{\partial{x}}+x\frac{\partial{z}}{\partial{y}} = -x$$
There is no need to change of variables. The result is directly obtained thanks to the method of characteristics.

Charpit-Lagrange characteristic ODEs :
$$\frac{dx}{z}=\frac{dy}{x}=\frac{dz}{-x}$$
A first characteristic equation comes from solving $\frac{dx}{z}=\frac{dz}{-x}$ :
$$x^2+z^2=c_1$$
A second characteristic equation comes from solving $\frac{dy}{x}=\frac{dz}{-x}$ :
$$z+y=c_2$$
The general solution of the PDE on the form of implicit equation $c_2=F(c_1)$ is :
$$z+y=F(x^2+z^2)$$
$F$ is an arbitrary function.
$$\boxed{z(x,y)=-y+F(x^2+z^2)}$$

One cannot expect to express $z(x,y)$ on explicit form without knowing what function $F$ is. Boundary condition is necessary to be specified in the wording of the question in order to determine the function $F$.

Bytheway, are you sure that there is no typo in your PDE : $z\frac{\partial{z}}{\partial{x}}+x\frac{\partial{z}}{\partial{y}}+x=0 $ ?

I guess that the PDE might be : $-y\frac{\partial{z}}{\partial{x}}+x\frac{\partial{z}}{\partial{y}}+x=0$ . This would be consistent with the proposed change of variables and the solution would be much simpler : $z=-y+F(x^2+y^2)$ and $v=F(u)$.

Answer (score 0):

Since $z = v - y$, we have
$$z \frac{\partial z}{\partial x} + x \frac{\partial z}{\partial y} + x 
= (v-y)\frac{\partial v}{\partial x} + x \frac{\partial v}{\partial y} =  0.$$

(Seemingly it is better to use $w = x^2 - y^2$.) We have

\begin{align}
2xy \frac{\partial v}{\partial w} = 2xy\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}\frac{\partial x}{\partial w} + 2xy\frac{\partial v}{\partial y}\frac{\partial y}{\partial w} = y\frac{\partial v}{\partial x} - x \frac{\partial v}{\partial y} = v \frac{\partial v}{\partial x}.
\end{align}

Similarly, if we use $u = x^2 + y^2$, then we have
\begin{align}
2xy \frac{\partial v}{\partial u} = 2xy\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}\frac{\partial x}{\partial u} + 2xy\frac{\partial v}{\partial y}\frac{\partial y}{\partial u} = y\frac{\partial v}{\partial x} + x \frac{\partial v}{\partial y} = v \frac{\partial v}{\partial x} + 2x\frac{\partial v}{\partial y}.
\end{align}

Comment: Many thanks for your answer! How would I continue this to find z(u,v)?